# Why does JavaScript show me one day before my set date?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I'm trying see dates based off of some json data I have.

My code is:

```
var date = new Date(json.events[i].event.first_date);
alert(date);
```

Now, that `json.events[i].event.first_date` just returns the date in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd`.

I noticed, however that when I do the `alert(date);`, I'm shown the day *before* the date that the actual data says.

For example, `json.events[0].event.first_date` gives the date `2015-06-02` but the alert shows June 1, 2015.

I am getting my json from a url based somewhere in Germany and I am in the US. Could the date be messed up because of timezones?

Comment: where is the javascript code running? In Germany or in the US?

Comment: @cacho - jsfiddle. So.. I'm guessing US.

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Comment: @Arvind seems to show the same thing.

Comment: After concatenating ' 00:00:00 GMT' to my Date string ('Thu Oct 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT') I got the correct date. (Since I don't need the time anyway).

new Date('Thu Oct 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT')

Comment: just concat the time  'T00:00'  , eg: var date = new Date(json.events[i].event.first_date +'T00:00' );

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create date from string without timezone you get a date + timezone correction – if you're in USA then you have something like GMT-7 and you get the second of June minus 7 hours – the previous day. Try splitting your date and use `new Date(2015, 7, 1)` constructor and you'll get date you're expecting. String parse reference docs -https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse